# Why do I have more packets than bytes?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, ifconfig, statistics

I don't know how to explain this. mind blown.

```
ip -s link

2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether RE:DA:CT:ED:13:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    169229624  503669895 0       0       0       0      
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    3428505677 824829694 0       0       0       0
```

EDIT: 7 minutes later:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether RE:DA:CT:ED:13:37 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    RX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped overrun mcast   
    233622183  504425566 0       0       0       0      
    TX: bytes  packets  errors  dropped carrier collsns 
    891565814  825923772 0       0       0       0
```

now if someone could explain the decrease. I'm suspecting an integer overflow.

I don't have access to other end of the connection(it's a VPS) but they report 1~4 TiB monthly and the server has been up for about 4 days now so it should be 120GiB~500GiB.

Comment: Possible causes, SYN attack, ARP flood, others, multicast(?). Without monitoring data from your part, this is a very vague question. This question is not in the scope of Unix & Linux. I would recommend our sister forums "Network Engineering", or if properly worded, "Information Security". Remember cross-posting is not allowed.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro ty, I'll try that if I don't get an answer here within the hour.

Comment: Sniff the data with tcpdump. The counters have a 4GB limit, upon which they wrap around to 0

Comment: Too much unknown for a proper answer.  The estimate on what you think it should be at is unreliable to explain this specific case.  Richard's answer may be right but it's impossible to validate unless you have access to actual traffic information for the last 4 days.

Comment: The sun is rising where I am. I'll read the source for ip and ifconfig and see what's wrong later. if I get something good I'll post it here as an answer. tnx guys

Comment: you d better read stevens tcp illustrated edition 2. in corporate settings I often have netflows of at least 2 or 3 months

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending very small quantities of data at a time then it could happen:

- For every transmit you will receive an ack, possibly with zero byte payload.
- For every receive you will transmit an ack, possibly with zero byte payload.
- For every new connection you will transmit/receive a syn, a syn/ack, and an ack. (probably all with zero payload)

There may be other packets with zero payload/bytes.
Does not seem probably if you have sent/received 120GiB in 4 days though.

Comment: Doesn't it account in everything that crosses the wire? incl. ether and ip headers?

Comment: I'll check this.